# Getting calls from a colleague on off day?

Tags: professionalism, communication, colleagues

Right now, I am getting calls from a senior co-worker. And I don't feel like picking up the phone. I am afraid he is gonna ask me to go to workplace to do some work(it has happened before) I am currently not working with him in his project. But on a side project. I could be reassigned with him later on though.

Should I pick up?

I don't want to do it. It's weekend, it's my day off and I have a life too. He could have warned me before.

Comment: Which country? Do you have any obligation to work during weekend? Is overtime paid?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti The project in which senior is working on requires that. He has even been given laptop for that. For overtime you could get a comp off. But my point is, isn't it his work? Why should I do it! Every time.

Comment: The question is: is he entitled to call you? You seem to say that he is. It seems that you do not wish to do it, despite you being expected to do it. Which one of these is the case?

Comment: @CaptainEmacs "is he entitled to call you?" I don't know if he is. He is not the manager. "despite you being expected to do it. " (This is what I think he is expecting). As I said, I am not working with him currently. So why should I?
Before he has been giving me bits of things to do. I do it, because I like to help. But there is a limit.

Comment: You were not indoors, and your mobile phone was with your home phone. You didn't hear it ringing, so how could you possibly pick up?

Comment: @Shad Only you can answer this question. What does your contract or your boss say?

Comment: Contract says...we may be needed to do work on weekends if it is required. But shouldn't that be him? He is the one directly engaging with the client doing the work. I am a junior.

Comment: @gnasher729 wouldn't that leave a bad impression on him? That I am not assertive in such situations?

Comment: @shad "we may be needed" - if "we" includes you, the next question is who determines the "need". You make the inference that "we" talks about seniors, not juniors, but where does this inference comes from?

Comment: @CaptainEmacs  I am not making  senior, junior inference. But 'currently', he is working on project A and me on B. So if there is an urgency with A why should I of all people go? I have worked with him on A before and maybe in future as well be shifted to A. But currently, since I am on B. I don't think it should be my business.

Comment: Then pick up the phone and tell him. Also I'd not guess if your contract says you might need to.

Comment: @Shad All these questions show that we know even less about your situation than you do. I think you need to give the SE community more information about what your role is, what your senior's entitlement is etc. before you will get a useful reply. We can not decide whether it may be politically savvy for you to help him or actually the opposite, namely opening a door for him that you are available every weekend. Too much depends on the details of the situation.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti And why would that be a good move?

Comment: @CaptainEmacs Noted.

Comment: Because he doesn't know if he has to work or not then best bet is to ask. IMHO.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere you are right. will be trying.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs I ended up calling him in the evening. And he said he was out of city so was the other person in project A and there was this issue stuck and asked if I was free tom also apologized for disturbing? I ended up saying yes.

Comment: @Shad Ok, that sounds like a reasonable solution. My experience is to keep gauging what is an appropriate extra mile and what is a systematic breaching of boundaries. Obviously you start getting good at that; good luck!

Comment: @Shad Why would not carrying your phone with you on your day off leave a bad impression? In the summer, people like going to the beach, and sand and phones are known to be enemies, so you'd leave your phone at home. Or you just forget it. Or you want to enjoy your weekend, which is _very_ assertive.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unless you're paid to be 'on call' then you have no obligation to pick up. There may be consequences if you don't, but it's your choice.